# Conditionally adding to a collection

Tags: clojure

I want to add something to a collection based on a condition and leave it alone otherwise.

I found myself writing something like this:

```clj
(defn make-zoo
  [zoo has-ice]
  (let [zoo (if has-ice (conj zoo "penguins") zoo)]
    zoo))

(make-zoo ["tigers"] false) ;["tigers"] 
(make-zoo ["polar bears"] true) ;["polar bears" "penguins"]
```

I'm pretty new to Clojure, but this seems like a clunky solution for a common operation. Is there a more elegant way to address this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can simplify `make-zoo` using the `cond->` macro, a conditional derivative of the `->` threading macro:

```
(defn make-zoo [zoo has-ice]
  (cond-> zoo, has-ice (conj "penguins")))
```

Answer (score 3):

One simplification is to just leave out the `let` statement:

```
(defn make-zoo
  [zoo has-ice]
  (if has-ice
    (conj zoo "penguins")
    zoo))

(make-zoo ["tigers"] false) => ["tigers"]
(make-zoo ["polar bears"] true) => ["polar bears" "penguins"]
```